# Is there a way to buffer NSNotifications until the observer is ready?

Tags: objective-c, ios

One part of my program sends `NSNotification`s in irregular intervals. First some messages regarding the initial setup, then stuff triggered by GPS. The view controller that should observe those notifications takes some time to fire up and therefore usually misses the first few of them, though the `addObserver:` stuff is in `viewDidLoad`. So, is there a way for the view controller to get the messages it missed?

I am aware that I could send the whole message history with every notification, but still it would take until the next trigger event until anything is sent, and that would be too long.

Is there a standard approach to this, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create some NSObject where you store the messages. Then if the view that needs to listen to the notifications is loaded, check for any messages stored in the NSObject (so you won't need to wait for a new triggered message).

You are not missing something, you just need to change the way you handle the data a bit and it'll work perfectly :)

Comment: Thank you, but I think that would break the lose coupling you aim for when using notifications. So far, I don't need to tell my view controller who sends the content, and I don't need to tell the sending part who is the view controller. This makes things a lot more flexible. If this is the only way, I'll have to give that up, but I'd prefer not to. :)

Comment: Thinking about it, I could of course put that storage object in some central place...

Comment: That's what I meant. :) You can fill the NSObject with the messages if the listening view controller isn't loaded yet and give a sign to the NSObject when the listening view controller is indeed loaded so you can then send the messages that are stored and after that just instantly send a message, that would be stored, to the listening view controller. I hope you know what I mean, no enter makes a comment a big mess ;)